# In React Native can you prevent iOS's VoiceOver from automatically adding additional information to the end of an accessibilityLabel?

Tags: react-native, accessibility, voiceover

I have a React Native (0.66.4) app where there's a navbar component overlaying an image component. Inside the navbar component there's a button component that contains a React Native vector icon. There are two assumptions to be made: the image is a cat and the image component has `accessibilityLabel="Test"`.

With VoiceOver enabled on my iOS device, I click on the image and it reads "Test. Adult cat". Under VoiceOver Recognition, "Image Descriptions" is disabled. Is there a way ensure VoiceOver just says "Test"?

Comment: Could you post generated HTML code please ? It will be hard to help without code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Was very surprised that iOS would do that - especially since my wrapping view has `accessible`, so the content further down the tree shouldn't be noticed. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue here... Any news on this?